# How to upload file > 15GB to Google Service Account

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I am trying to upload a file > 15GB to a google service account, using this snippet from Google Drive:

- http://gsuitedevs.github.io/drive-utils/
- https://github.com/gsuitedevs/drive-utils/tree/master/upload

Is there a way to upload files larger than 15GB here? Or, a way to modify it so that it will upload to my personal Google Drive (where I'm paying for storage) instead of a service account that has that limitation? If so, how would I do so?

Comment: May be contact to google support?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention to use your own Google account instead of a service account

Answer (score 1):

There are a file storage limit on Google drive [Upload files to Google Drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en)

> Google Apps Free edition (legacy) Individual consumer accounts    15 GB

If you do an [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about/get) you will see how much space the service account has access to.   Service accounts are basic users and there is no way that i know of to give it more space.

**Granting it access to your account**

You can take the service account email address and share a folder on your google drive account with the service account.  It will then have access to upload to that folder.